# Add ListView everytime a new entry in database is made

Tags: java, mysql, listview, javafx, mqtt

I need help for my student project.
Currently I'm making a chat application using JavaFX, MQTT and Mysql.
I want to make an userlist (which user are online)

I tried this so that a new user would send a message through a special topic, and all will be "secretely" subscribing this topic it'll receive the message (using callback) and call the method insertingMysql() and updatingList(). But somehow it does not work.

This is where I give the username

```
public static void logging(String username) throws MqttException {
    if(username != null && !username.isEmpty()) {
        MysqlDatabase.insertingMysql(username);
        window.close();
    }
}
```

This is to add ListView

```
public static void addItem(String item) {
    userList.getItems().add(item);
}
```

This is the part where I have problems with (I think)

```
public class MysqlDatabase {

static String topic_body = "chat";;
static String topic_ext = "userList";

static MqttCallback sqlCallback = new MqttCallback() {
    @Override
    public void connectionLost(Throwable thrwbl) {
    }

    @Override
    public void messageArrived(String string, MqttMessage mm) throws Exception {
        String username = new String(mm.getPayload());
        System.out.println(username); // Checking

        updatingList();
    }

    @Override
    public void deliveryComplete(IMqttDeliveryToken imdt) {
    }
};

public static void sqlConnection() {
    try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.println("Connected");
}

public static void mqttConnection(String username) throws MqttException {
    MqttClient sqlClient = new MqttClient("tcp://iot.eclipse.org:1883", username);
    sqlClient.connect();
    sqlClient.subscribe(topic_body + topic_ext + "#");
    sqlClient.setCallback(sqlCallback);

    MqttMessage sqlMessage = new MqttMessage();
    sqlMessage.setPayload((username).getBytes());
    sqlClient.publish(topic_body + "userlist", sqlMessage);
}

public static void insertingMysql(String username) throws MqttException {
    sqlConnection();
    String host = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/test";
    String user = "root";
    String password = "";
    try {
        Connection connect = DriverManager.getConnection(host, user, password);
        PreparedStatement statement = (PreparedStatement) connect.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO chat_test(username)VALUES(?)");
        statement.setString(1, username);
        statement.executeUpdate();
        statement.close();
        System.out.println("Inserted to database!");
        mqttConnection(username);
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        System.out.println("Error");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public static void updatingList() {
    sqlConnection();
    String host = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/test";
    String user = "root";
    String password = "";
    try {
        Connection connect = DriverManager.getConnection(host, user, password);
        PreparedStatement statement = (PreparedStatement) connect.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM chat_test");
        ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery();
        while(rs.next()) {
            String uName = rs.getString("username");
            System.out.println("Username: " + uName);
            JavaFXChat.addItem(uName);
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        System.out.println("Error");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 options here:

1. Database triggers. This is code that runs on the Database server when ever a table is changed. Normally these triggers are SQL statements but this blog (https://patternbuffer.wordpress.com/2012/09/14/triggering-shell-script-from-mysql/) post seams to talk about a plugin to support running a script that could send a MQTT message announcing the new user coming online.
2. Use MQTT messages and the Last Will and Testament feature. A users would publish a message to known topic then they come online, they would publish a similar message when going offline. The LWT can be used to automatically publish the offline message if the connetion drops due to problem. (details of LWT can be found here http://www.hivemq.com/blog/mqtt-essentials-part-9-last-will-and-testament

Comment: Well I've tried your method of publishing a message through a special topic. But got still some problem tho. Thanks anyway!

Comment: You will still need to send an explicit disconnect message before you close the connection to the broker cleanly, the LWT will only fire if the client misses a keep alive packet